# Accessing Windows Azure Queues from client side javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, azure, azure-storage

For a UI feature, I need to read from a Windows Azure queue and update the UI accordingly.

I see plenty of node.js examples, but nothing using pure Javascript or Jquery. ([azureQuery](http://azurequery.codeplex.com/documentation) comes close, but no queue functionality yet and it needs a Web API to talk to)

This is a hybrid web app using both asp.net and MVC 4. This particular page is generated  using MVC 4.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Roberto
(PS. being able to write to the queue would also be nice)

Comment: One alternative could be to put the contents of the queue into blob storage (maybe as json) and then use Javascript to poll for new items. Using the HTTP range and/or smart naming for the blobs this could be even reasonably efficient. This is certainly more complicated that running your own endpoint, but could be worth the trouble if read access to the queue is critical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible directly from the browser. JavaScript in the browser has to follow the same-origin policy, which means that JavaScript can only make calls to the domain of the current web page. Since your web page won't be served from `<account>.queue.windows.net`, it means your JavaScript won't be able to call APIs on that domain. (This would be possible in most browsers if the queue service served up [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) headers, but it doesn't.)

You'll need to host a web endpoint (in your MVC 4 app, probably) that proxies queue messages. Your JavaScript will send a message to your web app, and your web app will put the message on the queue.

Comment: You could JSONP to the queue if you created a shared access signature for it? Whether you could actually read the message is another matter.

Comment: @RichardAstbury JSONP is a protocol for a server returning JSON from a `<script>` tag request. I don't see how it applies here, since we have no control over the server's response. (It's the queue service, and we don't own it.)

Comment: It would apply if you could retrieve the message body without it being wrapped in XML. Then if your message was a JavaScript function, you could then do something on the page. However, as it stands, the browser encounters the first angle bracket in the message XML, and doesn't evaluate anything you put in the message body.

Comment: According to this MSDN blog they mentioned in Build conference this summer that CORS support would be coming before end of 2013: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/06/28/windows-azure-storage-build-talk-what-s-coming-best-practices-and-internals.aspx

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: Please see comments below and discard this answer.**

You can try fetching the list of messages using shared access signature (SAS) for queues. I just did a simple test where I created a SAS for queue with "Read" Permission. I get a URI something like this:

youraccount.core.queue.net/queuename?sv=2012-02-12&st=2012-10-11T04%3A31%3A53Z&se=2012-10-11T05%3A31%3A53Z&sp=raup&sig=PN4dyOoOIBlJPQbQ%2Bu7jDLyt%2FpIc3k2k1NZTei6q7Cg%3D

Using this I created a URI for peeking messages

youraccount.core.queue.net/queuename/**messages**?sv=2012-02-12&st=2012-10-11T04%3A31%3A53Z&se=2012-10-11T05%3A31%3A53Z&sp=r&sig=PN4dyOoOIBlJPQbQ%2Bu7jDLyt%2FpIc3k2k1NZTei6q7Cg%3D&**peekonly=true**

I then used this URI in my JavaScript code and traced the request in Fiddler. I was able to see response coming back from Windows Azure Storage.

Comment: Did you actually try this from a served page (not just a local file)? I would expect browsers to block this cross-domain request.

Comment: You're actually correct though I tried the code in TryIt editor on W3 Schools website so it was remote. I can see the request/response in Fiddler but gave me an error in JQuery.

Comment: Yeah, GET requests don't require a CORS preflight request, so they're just attempted and then aborted later when the CORS headers don't come back with the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Windows Azure Queue over REST interface using any supported language. With JavaScript your can make ajax calls to connect with Azure Storage Queue to read and write messages. Once you have JavaScript + Ajax based code in your hand, you just need to use [Azure Queue Storage REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179363.aspx) to perform any operation.

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/c1e5d77e-9692-45df-931a-46237a366493) is a sample using JavaScript to connect Azure Storage Queue. You can modify the code to connect to your real Azure Storage queue and it will fulfill your need:

Comment: Does that even work in the browser? What about the same origin policy?